# How can I check if my rectangles are out of bounds

Tags: d3.js, svg, rectangles

I have some random rectangles in random positions on the axis (1024x768) and I want to find which of them are going out of bounds so I can delete them, for example one of them is the rectangle S as it is shown in the following picture. How can I do that??

[image]

Comment: You can do something like this: If (rect.x >0 && rect.x < 1024 - rect.width && rect.y > 0 && rect.y < 768 - rect.height )

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. It removes all the rectangles that they are inside the 
 axis and keeps the rectangles that are going out of bounds. Instead, I tried this if((d.x + d.width)> width || (d.y + d.height)> height) and it worked but the opacity is gone. :/ do you have an idea why?

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you but it didn't work. It removes all the rectangles that they are inside the axis and keeps the rectangles that are going out of bounds. Instead, I tried this if((d.x + d.width)> width || (d.y + d.height)> height) and it worked but the opacity is gone. :/ do you have an idea why?